# C++ Server recv() command does not always receive send() from client

Tags: c++, tcp, server, client

I have a server that connects to a client and executes the following communication:

```cpp
void communicate(promise<long> && divisions, promise<long> && result, int sockt, long number, long prime) {
    send(sockt, number);
    send(sockt, prime);
    long div = receive(sockt);
    long res = receive(sockt);
    divisions.set_value(div);
    result.set_value(res);
}

void send(int sockt, long number) {
    string numberString;
    stringstream strstream;
    strstream << number;
    strstream >> numberString;
    cout << "Sending: " << number << endl;
    write(sockt, numberString.c_str(), sizeof numberString);
}

long receive(int sockt) {
    // receive string
    const unsigned int MAX_BUF_LENGTH = 1024;
    std::vector<char> buffer(MAX_BUF_LENGTH);
    std::string rcv;
    recv(sockt, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), 0);
    rcv.append(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend());

    //convert string to long
    string::size_type sz = 0;
    long val = stoll(rcv, &sz, 0);
    cout << "Received: " << val << endl;

    return val;
}
```

The client performs the same communication but in reverse:

```cpp
void communicate(){
    string number = receive(sockt);
    string prime = receive(sockt);
    // do stuff to the data
    send(sockt, divisions);
    send(sockt, val);
}
```

The problem is the server sometimes (after looping this communication 100+ times) does not receive the second sent message from the client and hangs.  The client never has trouble receiving a message from the server its always the server hanging. The server prints:

```
Sending: 344486269
Sending: 7
Received: 0
```

Then does not terminate so I know its awaiting the second value which never comes. The client prints:

```
Received: 344486269
Received: 7
Sending: 0
Sending: 344486269
```

So I know the client successfully performs its `send()` commands.

What could be causing the server to not properly receive the second message?

Comment: I suspect that if you are using tcp, when receiving you might have received past the end of the previous send (since in tcp you will receive packets in stream so you don't have a message boundary). One way to fix this is to have a constant message size (e.g: instead of using asciiz you use some fixed sized int), alternatively you could receive byte per byte and treat 0x00 as the end of tbe message.

Comment: You are almost certainly receiving both sends in a single receive. There are several other problems with this code, such as using `sizeof' instead of `strlen()`. Too broad.

Comment: So lets say I standardize the strings I'm sending to be 10 characters long, how would you modified my receive method to ensure I always receive a 10 character long string? Setting the size of the buffer to 10 bytes does not work for me.

Comment: Provide a 10 character buffer and use MSG_WAITALL.

Answer (score 0):

In `void send(int sockt, long number)`, your call to `write()` is faulty, for several reasons:

- `sizeof numberString` is the wrong number of bytes to send. That is the compile-time size of the `string` class, not the run-time byte size of the character data it points to.
- you are not delimiting the sent data in any way that allows the receiver to know when the data ends. When sending variable length data, you MUST either send the data length before sending the data, or else send a unique terminator after the data.
- you are not accounting for the possibility that `write()` can send fewer bytes than requested. You must call it in a loop until all of the desired bytes have  been fully sent.

Likewise, in `long receive(int sockt)`, you have similar issues related to `recv()`. You are calling it only one time without any regard to the size of the data being sent. And you are ignoring its return value to know how many bytes were actually read.

You need something more like the following instead:

```cpp
void send(int sockt, long number) {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << number;
    string numberString = oss.str();
    // or simply:
    // string numberString = to_string(number);

    cout << "Sending: " << numberString << endl;

    const char *ptr = numberString.c_str();
    string::size_type size = numberString.size() + 1;
    do {
        int written = write(sockt, ptr, size);
        if (written < 0) {
            // error handling as needed...
            return;
        }
        ptr += written;
        size -= written;
    }
    while (size > 0);
}

long receive(int sockt) {
    // receive string
    char ch;
    std::string rcv;
    do {
        if (recv(sockt, &ch, 1, 0) <= 0) {
            // error handling as needed...
            return -1;
        }
        if (ch == '\0') break;
        rcv += ch;
    }
    while (true);

    //convert string to long
    string::size_type sz = 0;
    long val = stoll(rcv, &sz, 0);
    cout << "Received: " << val << endl;

    return val;
}
```

However, a much better solution would be to simply send the `long` data in a fixed sized binary format instead of as a variable length string:

```cpp
void send(int sockt, long number) {
    uint32_t tmp = htonl(number);
    cout << "Sending: " << number << endl;
    char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp);
    size_t size = sizeof(tmp);
    do {
        int written = write(sockt, ptr, size);
        if (written < 0) {
            // error handling as needed...
            return;
        }
        ptr += written;
        size -= written;
    }
    while (size > 0);
}

long receive(int sockt) {
    // receive long
    uint32_t tmp;
    char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp);
    size_t size = sizeof(tmp);
    do {
        int recvd = recv(sockt, ptr, size, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0) {
            // error handling as needed...
            return -1;
        }
        ptr += recvd;
        size -= recvd;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    long val = ntohl(tmp);
    cout << "Received: " << val << endl;

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly I didn't think of a delimiter!